# Missing first line(s) using php_strip_whitespace

Tags: php, removing-whitespace

I am using the php function php_strip_whitespace to output a page "usefulFunction.php" that has one long function within it.

```
<?php

//phpCodeStripper

echo php_strip_whitespace       ("usefulFunction.php");

?>
```

I get back all the code, except for the first couple of lines of the function.

The output starts mid query... 'query("SELECT....' when original syntax read (from start of page, with comments deleted)

```
<?php 
function engine($one,   $two, $three, $conn){



if (
    (!isset($one)) OR
    (!isset($two)) OR
    (!isset($three)) OR
    (!isset($conn)) 
    ){
    $badInput = "some engine variable is missing!";
    return $badInput;
    unset($badInput);
}


require ( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "upfolder/thisfolder/functions.php");

    if($blahblah=='a'){


        $thisSpecialQuery = $conn ->query("SELECT....
```

What might be causing this?

Comment: Ok I'll get the code....

Comment: just change your header content type : `header("Content-Type: text/plain");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code seems to be good, but i think you have a problem with your display (It is interpreted as html tag) :

If you look at your source, or if you try with `htmlentities`, you should get all

```
echo htmlentities(php_strip_whitespace("usefulFunction.php"));
```

`>` before the query just acts as an html tag closure. Tha would explain why it starts appearing at this specifi point.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes of course!! Thanks! Manual 'could' mention it - maybe in the notes - since echoing php through html is so common and not everyone is as awake as you!